# zmq hangs in zmq_proxy() during the cleanup

Tags: c++, zeromq, distributed-system

I am using ZeroMQ, version 4.2.4, on Ubuntu machine (4.4.0-28-generic #47~14.04.1-Ubuntu).

I picked up **`mtserver.c`** from https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/mtserver.c.
The pattern is `REQ-ROUTER-DEALER-REP`. Below is a slightly modified version of the same code.

The problem - when I try to cleanly exit after all the workers threads done, the code is hanging in `zmq_proxy( clients, workers, NULL )`.

I tried with `LINGER` timer option on "clients" socket, but it did not help. Appreciate any help to help me debug. Thanks.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fd6a4febc9d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x00007fd6a58232fa in poll (__timeout=-1, __nfds=1, __fds=0x7ffd692d80e0) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/poll2.h:46
#2  zmq::signaler_t::wait (this=this@entry=0x1f09e28, timeout_=timeout_@entry=-1) at src/signaler.cpp:232
#3  0x00007fd6a5809f95 in zmq::mailbox_t::recv (this=0x1f09dc0, cmd_=0x7ffd692d8140, timeout_=-1) at src/mailbox.cpp:81 
#4  0x00007fd6a582497d in zmq::socket_base_t::process_commands (this=this@entry=0x1f09850, timeout_=timeout_@entry=-1, 
throttle_=throttle_@entry=false) at src/socket_base.cpp:1341
#5  0x00007fd6a5824ee3 in zmq::socket_base_t::send (this=this@entry=0x1f09850, msg_=msg_@entry=0x7ffd692d83d0, flags_=<optimized out>)
at src/socket_base.cpp:1156
#6  0x00007fd6a5819d24 in forward (from_=from_@entry=0x1f077a0, from_stats=from_stats@entry=0x7ffd692d8330, to_=to_@entry=0x1f09850, 
to_stats=to_stats@entry=0x7ffd692d8350, capture_=capture_@entry=0x0, msg_=...) at src/proxy.cpp:147
#7  0x00007fd6a581a7d3 in zmq::proxy (frontend_=0x1f077a0, backend_=0x1f09850, capture_=0x0, control_=0x0) at src/proxy.cpp:462
#8  0x00000000004018b2 in zmqMTServer::Start (this=this@entry=0x7ffd692d84e0) at mtserver.cpp:75
#9  0x0000000000401207 in main () at mtserver.cpp:89
```

(gdb

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
bool zmqServerShutdown = false;

class zmqMTServer {
private:
    ushort workerThreads;
void* zmqContext;
unique_ptr<thread[]> workerThreadIDs;
void workerRoutine(void);

public:
    zmqMTServer(ushort threads) : workerThreads(threads)
    {
        zmqContext = zmq_ctx_new();
        assert(zmqContext);
        auto rc = zmq_ctx_set(zmqContext, ZMQ_IO_THREADS, 1);
        assert(rc == 0);
        rc = zmq_ctx_set(zmqContext, ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS, ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS_DFLT);
        assert(rc == 0);
    }
    int Start(void);
    ~zmqMTServer(void)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < workerThreads; i++)
            workerThreadIDs[i].join();
        zmq_ctx_destroy(zmqContext);
    }
};

void zmqMTServer::workerRoutine(void) 
{
    void *receiver = zmq_socket(zmqContext, ZMQ_REP);
    assert(receiver);
    auto rc = zmq_connect(receiver, "inproc://workerThreads");
    assert(rc == 0);
    cout << "Worker thread(" << this_thread::get_id() << ") started \n";
    while (!zmqServerShutdown) {
        char buf[256];
        auto size = zmq_recv(receiver, buf, 255, 0);
        if (size == -1) {
            cout << "workerRoutine(): zmq_recv size = " << size << "\n";
            continue; // some thing went wrong
        }
        buf[size] = '\0';
        cout << "Worker thread(" << this_thread::get_id() << ") Received request: " << buf << "\n";

        size = zmq_send(receiver, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    }
    cout << "zmqMTServer worker thread exiting " << this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
    rc = zmq_close(receiver);
}

int zmqMTServer::Start(void)
{
    void *clients = zmq_socket(zmqContext, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    assert(clients);

    auto rc = zmq_bind(clients, "tcp://*:10051");
    assert(rc == 0);
    void *workers = zmq_socket(zmqContext, ZMQ_DEALER);
    rc = zmq_bind (workers, "inproc://workerThreads");
    assert(rc == 0);

    //  Launch pool of worker threads
    workerThreadIDs = unique_ptr<thread[]>(new thread[workerThreads]);
    for(auto i = 0; i < workerThreads; i++) {
        workerThreadIDs[i] = thread(&zmqMTServer::workerRoutine, this);
    }

    zmq_proxy(clients, workers, NULL);

    zmq_close(clients);
    zmq_close(workers);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int major, minor, patch;
    zmq_version(&major, &minor, &patch);
    cout << "ZMQ version : " << major << "." << minor << "." << patch << "\n";

    zmqMTServer server(3);
    server.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>[+1] for analytical thoughts about using `ZMQ_LINGER`</sup>

---

### Oh those cheap and poor examples v/s real  world Distributed systems

On a fast look, the code, borrowed from a school-book example, **suffers** from using a blocking mode of the **`zmq_recv(...)`** operations.

Better design a distributed system in principally non-blocking manner. This way you never lose a control. Yes, most examples and school-book code-snippets still show up with blocking reads, but this is a thing that shall never appear in a serious production code.

Why? Because if nothing else, the blocking-state moves you out of the game and you may just stand praying for an external event to happen. If it will not happen, your precious code will remain hanging in the winds...

> **`zmq.h`**

```
#define ZMQ_DONTWAIT 1
...
#define ZMQ_NOBLOCK ZMQ_DONTWAIT
```

So, redesign a message-awaiting part so as to use a `zmq_poll()`, equipped  with some reasonably short ( or straight zero ) timeout, and follow each POSACKed message arrival with a non-blocking read:

```
zmq_recv( ...., ZMQ_NOBLOCK );
```

This way your code will never get left waiting inside any of the context-instance(s) thread(s) blocked.

[distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) simply cannot afford to get hung up.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code and pointing me in the right direction. This code has two issues: 1) blocking reads/writes (you pointed); 2) Not breaking out of zmq_proxy(). I have fixed blocking reads/writes with **zmq_poll()**. And replaced **zmq_proxy()** with **zmq_proxy_steerable(clients, workers, NULL, control)**. On the 'control' socket,  I sent **TERMINATE** from signal handler (it is slightly involved). Then every thing worked perfectly. I will share the code.